# Regex pattern for multi equal operation

Tags: java, regex

My goal is to compare one string with multiple other strings for equal operation using only regex in java 8.
I used below syntax

```
"^UK (Main Land)|German|Japan|Swiss|French|Italian$"
```

But this syntax works good for German,Japan,Swiss,French  but validation fails for UK (Main Land) and Italian.

What the change that I have to make it work?

Comment: It should be `"^(?:UK \\(Main Land\\)|German|Japan|Swiss|French|Italian)$"`

Comment: Ok Thank you. Let me check if it works.

Comment: This will create exact match right? not like contains operator right?

Comment: `^` and `$` are applied to each alternative inside the group.

Comment: Does the answer below help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here.

1. The parentheses, as literal chars, must be escaped.
2. If you use `Matcher.find()`, you need the `^` and `$` anchors to make sure the pattern matches the entire string (although `\A` and `\z` would be better), but you need to *group* the alternatives with either `(...)` or `(?:...)`.
3. You do not need the group and anchors if you use `String.matches()` or `Pattern.matches` that ensure an entire string match.

I'd rather use

```java
Boolean result = text.matches("UK \\(Main Land\\)|German|Japan|Swiss|French|Italian");
```